# How To Use Both Early Stop And Cross validation to do variable selection and parameter selection

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection

Here this the case I met, I was training GBM Classifier for a binary classification problem, I need to do forward stepwise variable selection and then do parameter selection. Both step I user CV as measurement. First problem is in variable selection I notice a fixed num trees is not good for a different size of variable size(as steps goes on,more variable added to the model), so I add Early stop, Does it correct? Second problem is in model Selection I want to user early stop but I found in different (train, valid) the early stop rounds is very different, how to decide the final rounds of final model and does it the correct way to do it?